# SQL where filter with 2 date fields with todays date

Tags: mysql, date

[image: database table]
i am trying to count row when SQL statement is executed.

i got 7 task (row) assign to **user id** = 1 in table name **project_scope**.

i want get the total number of **task delayed** form **completion_date** column less then **today's date**.
skip any task(row) **progress** field equal to 100, that's a completed task.

***i achieve that by:***

`"SELECT * FROM project_scope WHERE assing_to = '1' AND progress < 100 AND completion_date < '$today'"`

**BUT IF/WHEN**

look at first row, that task has an 2_completion_date (2nd completion date), this date is given in any case if the user unable to complete the take project leader will give another date to complete the task.

if **2_completion_date** field is more then today's date , that row should not be count.

**my question is?**

how to include **2_completion_date** in the SQL that filter both **completion_date** and **2_completion_date** filed together.

***i try these so far:***

```
SELECT * FROM project_scope WHERE assing_to = '$uid' AND progress < 100 AND (completion_date < '$today' OR 2_completion_date < '$today')
```

But output is 0 rows.

Comment: Maybe take a look at COALESCE()

Comment: `and coalesce(2_completion_date, completion_date) < '$today'`  coalesce takes the first non-null value in a series of values.  by putting 2_completion_date first if it's null it will use completion_date, otherwise use 2_completion_date for the evaluation

Comment: coalesce(2_completion_date, completion_date) < '$today' WORKS, Thanks every one !!